# great expectation with delta table

Tags: databricks, delta-lake, great-expectations, data-quality

I am trying to run a great expectation suite on a delta table in Databricks. But I would want to run this on part of the table with a query. Though the validation is running fine, it's running on full table data.

I know that I can load a Dataframe and pass it to Batch Request but I would like to load the data directly with query.

```
batch_request = RuntimeBatchRequest(
    datasource_name="datasource",
    data_connector_name="data_quality_run",
    data_asset_name="Input Data",
    runtime_parameters={"path": "/delta table path"},
    batch_identifiers={"data_quality_check": f"data_quality_check_{datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')}"},
    batch_spec_passthrough={"reader_method": "delta", "reader_options": {"header": True}, "query" : {"name":"John"}},
)
```

Above batch request loading the data ignoring the query option. Is there any way to pass the query for delta table in the batch request

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put `query` inside of `runtime_parameters`.

This works for me when I am querying data in SQL Server:

```py
batch_request = RuntimeBatchRequest(
    datasource_name="my_mssql_datasource",
    data_connector_name="default_runtime_data_connector_name",
    data_asset_name="default_name",
    runtime_parameters={
        "query": "SELECT * from dbo.MyTable WHERE Created = GETDATE()"
    },
    batch_identifiers={"default_identifier_name": "default_identifier"},
)
```

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't work with delta table. I have got "splitter_method" which needs to be passed in the specification on batch to filter based on column